# Web2py - request.vars.values()[0] - can't define

Tags: python, variables, web2py

What would be the possible reasons for getting the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Whilst it's trying to define:

```
partialstr = request.vars.values()[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990860/web2py-ajax-search/6996683#6996683), you should use `request.vars.partialstr` rather than `request.vars.values()[0]` -- the former will simply return `None`if `partialstr` doesn't exist.

Comment: This simple fix solved all my problems, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the list-like thing returned by `request.vars.values()` has no elements, then this error would be expected -- you would be trying to access the first element in an empty list.

Try displaying `len(request.vars.values())`.  If it is `0` then that's your problem.